# How should I explain that probationary period ended to my next job interview?

Tags: contracts, probation

I was suppose to be in my regularization panel interview. But on the last minute my boss said that I will end my probationary contract. My supervisor told me that there was no problems in the projs I handled and I improved. The only problem is that their system changed, they now look to the number of producted works(projects) regardless of the quantity in each project. I work as a creative designer. and we had no over time pay. My boss advise me to still render over time but i don't want to. and I think it was a factor of me not reaching their target number. On the day that I will suppose to sign the end of contract since I finish my six probationary contract I was advised by the HR to make a resignation letter because they say it was better. But I got a bad feeling on that sudden notice so I decided to just end the contract not resign since i finish six months

I am now preparing for my next job. That was my first job after graduating in college. How can I better explain the reason I ended job? I just want that job for experience. Looking forward for your response. Thank you!

My previous job was 2 hrs far from where I live. A total of 4 hrs back and forth.

Comment: Location matters.

Comment: I'm guessing the location is somewhere in France, considering op's username.

Answer (score 1):

"The position I held previously was not a good fit. I look forward to using my talents in a growing company in which I can evolve to better fit the needs of my clients."

Comment: If asked why do I think I am not a good fit. Should I mention the reason my previous company gives me on why my contract for regularization ended? or I can just say I am looking for better opportunities

Comment: It depends on how transparent you want to be. I would mention that you felt there were better opportunities. I'm afraid that if you go into it losing negatives, a prospective employer may not be able to see oat them.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a problem explaining to a prospective employer why you chose to end your contract without going into a lot of detail:

"I accepted the contract knowing that it was a good opportunity to gain experience in my field and challenge me professionally. The only negative was the distance of the commute--two hours each way. I underestimated how difficult the commute would be, but I stuck it out until the end of my contract. At the end of my contract, I opted not to renew and, instead, seek new opportunities closer to home."

No one would question that reasoning for a second. Make sure you mention, despite the difficulties, you fulfilled your contract.

Comment: I'm presuming that the reason he didn't want to do overtime is the fact that he was already spending four hours a day commuting to and from the job. If he lived closer, the likelihood is that overtime wouldn't have been as big of a deal. I'm also figuring, based on what the supervisor told him, is that the fact he wouldn't do overtime contributed to him not getting retained because his productivity wasn't high enough. I didn't read anything that said he was a bad employee. What I read was he needs to work closer to home. That's the truth.